# MySQL service won't start

Tags: linux, mysql, rhel-7

After needing to reset the root password of a MySQL instance I went to restart my service and retrieved the following error from `mysqld.log`

```
[System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 3253
[ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
[ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
[ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
[ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
[ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

From what I've read online, something with `my.cnf` or directory permissions of my `/var/lib/mysql` (750) may be off.

I'm a bit out of my element, but I did not find `journalctl -xe` or `systemctl status` to be very helpful.

My `my.cnf` file contains the following:

```
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
port=3306
#--skip_networking=0
#user=mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
tmpdir = /var/lib/mysql/tmp
```

Can anyone help troubleshoot so I can get this up and running again?

Comment: Can you post add a copy of my.cnf? Sounds like it can't find one of the innodb files. Check the ownership of /var/lib/mysql too if you suspect a permission problem.

Comment: @Greig permssions are 750 and the my.cnf is `#bind-address=127.0.0.1
port=3306
#--skip_networking=0
#user=mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
tmpdir = /var/lib/mysql/tmp`

I ended up being able to do a fresh install because I hadn't actually made anything yet. Permission needed to be 751 and most my.cnf wasn't needed. Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Just read the rest of your comment. 751 is a bit odd, but I guess there will be a reason somewhere. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `my.cnf` file looks fairly normal, so I'm guessing its more or less a default package install.

Check that `/var/lib/mysql` exists. The permissions on it should be 700 and it should be owned by the MySQL user (probably `mysql`) with group `mysql`.

Inside that folder you should find an `ibdata1` file with permissions `660` again owned and grouped to the `mysql` user.

It's the `ibdata1` file that MySQL can't find.

Take a note of all of the existing permissions and owners in case you need to switch them back and try these two commands:

```
chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql

chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

You might need to put sudo before those two commands.

If you can't find the folder or the ibdata1 file then you have a different problem.